# Finding sum of a given range of integers (positive only) in Java

Tags: java, integer, formula

Write a program to sum up all the positive numbers from n1 to n2, both inclusive and store it in a variable n. Your program should print the message "The sum of n2 - n1 numbers is " followed by the value of the sum (n).

Now this is my code :

/*Write your code here */

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class NumSum{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       int n=0;           
       System.out.println("The sum of n2-n1 numbers is "+sum(n));
    }
    public static int sum(int n){
         int n1,n2;

         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         n1=sc.nextInt();
         n2=sc.nextInt();
         int a=n1;
         n=n2-n1+1;
         int d=1;
         int x=0;
         //if(n1>0&&n2>0){
           // for(int i=n1;i<=n2;i++){
           //     n+=i;
           // }
         //}else 
         if(n1<0&&n2>0){
            x=n*(2*a+(n-1)*d)/2;               
         }else if(n1>0&&n2>0){
            x=n*(2*a+(n-1)*d)/2;
         }else if(n1<0&&n2<0){
            x=0;
         }else if(n1>0&&n2<0){
            x=0;
         }
         return x;
    }
}
```

But it is not accepting the test cases given in above question ?
Can anybody help ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9lNO.png)

Comment: what do you mean by not accepting?

Comment: I don't know test cases are what are asked in question !

Comment: Where do you input the values of `n1` and `n2`?? And why is there a a big blank space in the main method???

Comment: in the function sum()

Comment: What is `n` even doing? What do you wish to achieve from `sum(0)`?

Comment: Now ANYBODY ? PLEASE HELP !

Comment: If your code doesn't work for the test cases, you need to look at what inputs case it to fail and see why it doesn't produce the expected result.

Comment: I suspect you are expected to write a `sum` method which sums up to `n` and to calculate the difference do `sum(n2) - sum(n1-1)`

Comment: Exactly I am not able to understand the question itself ? Do you understood  @PeterLawrey ?

Comment: @PavanPutraBoy, No disrespect is meant, but please do not start off with, "Here is my code", and with a series of, "But I don't think this is it; do you think this is what I need?" Please try to interpret your question before you ask. From what I understand you seem to be summing up successive integers from **m** to **n** (inclusive). Does using a formula like **n(n+1)/2 - m(m-1)/2** suit your needs?

Comment: @blackpen And what if the one of them or both are negative ?

Comment: @blackpen According to your concept : `class NumSum{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      
       int n1,n2,x=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        n1=sc.nextInt();
        n2=sc.nextInt();
        if(n1>0&&n2>0){
            x=n2*(n2+1)/2-n1*(n1-1)/2;
        }
         System.out.println("The sum of n2- n1 is "+x);
      
    }
}` But it is not working !

Comment: @PavanPutraBoy, Your question mentions "Positive Numbers n1 to n2" (with implied meaning that n2>=n1). Do you want to change your question and add the desired outputs to your post?

Comment: if you can provide your own answer then please do it ! I will be very thankful  .

Comment: @PavanPutraBoy, I added the formula in the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's only positive numbers you should add, make `n1 = 0` if `n1` is negative. The formula to find sum of first `n` numbers is `(n^2+n)/2`. 
 Lower limit (`n1`) should be decreased by `1` before applying the formula, as limits are included to the sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class NumSum{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("The sum of n2-n1 numbers is "+sum());
    }
    public static int sum(){
          int n1,n2;

         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        n1=sc.nextInt();
        n2=sc.nextInt();

        int tmp;

        if(n1 > n2)
        {
           tmp = n1;
           n1 = n2;
           n2 = tmp;
        } 

        n1--;

        if(n1<0)
          n1 = 0;
        if(n2<0)
          return 0;


        int sum1 = (n1*n1 + n1)/2;
        int sum2 = (n2*n2 + n2)/2;

        return sum2 - sum1;

    }
}
```

Comment: test cases are still not passed !

Comment: Any constraints given in the question regarding `n1` and `n2`?

Comment: Now see image above !

Comment: You should try this yourself. I hope the question is not from an ongoing competition

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sum up integers in range from a to b (inclusive; with a and b allowed to be positive, negative; a<=b), consider it as a series:

```
    a+0, a+1, a+2, .... a+k (b is conviniently termed as a+k)
```

The parts can be summed up as:

```
    (k+1)*a + k(k+1)/2
```

Eliminating k, gives you the formula:

```
    [(b-a+1)(a+b)]/2
```

When b>a, you need to swap a and b.

Take care with java's integer division. Modify the formula if you have further exceptions that are not covered here.

```
class NumSum {
   public static int sum_range(int a, int b) {
      if (a>b) return(sum_range(b,a));
      return(((b-a+1)*(a+b))/2);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int i=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int j=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      System.out.println("Sum: " + sum_range(i,j));
   }
}
```